# How can I replace the value of variable from the another file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

This code is working,but only for string and I need replace the value of the variable.

```
'string-replace': {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          //cwd: 'src/',
          src: '<%= mifosx.app %>/scripts/initialTasks.js',
          //dest: 'dist/'
        }],
        options: {
          replacements: [{
            pattern: 'sffffsss',
            replacement: 'google'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which value work as string and with what do you want to replace it?

Comment: f.ex here pattern: 'sffffsss',  replacement: 'google' I change sffffsss with google.Now I have variable var test = 'something' inside of initialTasks.js and how can I get the value of variable test

Answer (score 0):

With `Grunt`/`Gulp`, I usually see resources consumed using `require` (CommonJS). To get the variable into your Grunt file, you'll need to export the variable.

```
// fileWithVar.js
module.exports = {
  pattern: 'something'
};
```

And then, from your Grunt file…

```
const myFile = require('./fileWithVar');
console.log(myFile.pattern); // 'something'
```

Once you have the variable in scope, you'll simply drop it into your task:

```
options: {
  replacements: [{
    pattern: myFile.pattern,
    replacement: 'google'
  }]
}
```